# Ubhind app not working properly after android security update for 5.1.1

Tags: applications, updates, nexus-5, 5.1-lollipop

I have a nexus 5 and the android version is 5.1.1.I have been using the app Ubhind for controlling how much time I spend on the mobile device. After the security update from android this month the app seems to have lost all right to device administration even though the app has full access .